# Javax Persistence Many to Many Collection EclipseLink JPA 2.1

Tags: java, jpa, collections, eclipselink, derby

Using Netbeans to develop embedded database application (Derby).  I am trying to figure out how the many to many relationship works.  Netbeans created the entity classes for me.  I understand how to retrieve a record and commit new results to the record but I am not familiar with how you would commit a "collection"  see the code below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MASTER")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({....
})
public class Master implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "SDS_NUMBER")
private Integer sdsNumber;
@Column(name = "PRODUCT_NAME")
private String productName;
@Column(name = "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION")
private String productDescription;
@Column(name = "SDS_FILE_NAME")
private String sdsFileName;
@Column(name = "USE_STATUS")
private Boolean useStatus;
@Column(name = "DATA_UPDATED")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dataUpdated;
@Column(name = "PROPER_SHIPPING_NAME")
private String properShippingName;
@Column(name = "SIGNAL_WORD")
private String signalWord;
@Column(name = "GHS_COMPLIANT")
private Boolean ghsCompliant;
@JoinTable(name = "STATEMENT_LOOKUP", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "SDS_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "SDS_NUMBER")},
     inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATEMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "STATEMENT_ID")})
@ManyToMany
private Collection<Statements> statementsCollection;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "masterCollection")
private Collection<Manufacturers> manufacturersCollection;
@JoinTable(name = "PICTOGRAM_LOOKUP", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "SDS_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "SDS_NUMBER")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "PICTOGRAM_ID", referencedColumnName = "PICTOGRAM_ID")})
@ManyToMany
private Collection<Pictograms> pictogramsCollection;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "masterCollection")
private Collection<Locations> locationsCollection;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "masterCollection")
private Collection<Keywords> keywordsCollection;

public Master() {
}

public Master(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}  Getters and Setters follow.......
    @XmlTransient
public Collection<Keywords> getKeywordsCollection() {
    return keywordsCollection;
}

public void setKeywordsCollection(Collection<Keywords> keywordsCollection) {
    this.keywordsCollection = keywordsCollection;
}


public class NewClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = 
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JavaApplication20PU");
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction userTransaction = em.getTransaction();

userTransaction.begin();
Master record = new Master();
record.setProductName("Test Product Name");
record.setProductDescription("Test Product Description");
record.setProperShippingName("Proper shipping name test");
record.setSdsNumber(999);
record.setSignalWord("WARNING");
record.setUseStatus(false);
record.setGhsCompliant(false);
record.setKeywordsCollection();// This is where I need help!
em.persist(record);
userTransaction.commit();
em.close();
entityManagerFactory.close();
}
}
```

Above is the code from my test class that populates the record.  The commented line is where I need help. Ultimately this needs to be populated with selections from a Jlist but any generic help or link to somewhere I can learn better how this works would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this tutorial a good one , good example and you can see some working examples with DER's.

[Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/)

And also it is not a Jlist it is a List or ArrayList, possible typo error XD. In your test you are not adding a list of keywords to the Master.